# Does $\wp(A \cap B) = \wp(A) \cap \wp(B)$ hold? How to prove it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently working on some discrete mathematics work and I've encountered a question I'm not sure how to answer exactly. Precisely, I'm trying to prove that two power, intersected sets statements are equal to each other and my understanding of how to do that doesn't seem to be enough. The statements in question go as follows:

> Determine whether, for any sets $A$ and $B$, through proof, it is true that
>   $$\wp(A \cap B) = \wp(A) \cap \wp(B)$$
>   where $\wp$ denotes a power set.

Should I make some form of example set to better understand how these statements are equivalent? Or even a venn diagram? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Venn diagrams can be a bit awkward when dealing with power sets. You could look at a couple of small examples, but in this case your best approach may be simply to try to prove it, and either succeed or see where you run into difficulties; the latter often gives a clue towards finding a counterexample.

So try to show first that $\wp(A\cap B)\subseteq\wp(A)\cap\wp(B)$. Suppose that $X\in\wp(A\cap B)$; then $X\subseteq A\cap B$. Therefore ...

If you can complete that argument successfully, you can try showing the opposite inclusion.